# How to center a div with dynamic & static content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, center

Ok, I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_inner">
        <div id="header_image">
            <a href=""><img src="..."/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="header_content">
            <h1 id="header_content_h1">Dynamic Content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to center the div with id `header_inner`.

But my issue is that the div with id `header_content` contains dynamic content, so it can be any width.

Currently I solve this by setting the width of `header_inner` using Javascript at `window.onload` and the normal css for centering div's (`margin:auto;`), but this causes the content to load initially on the left of the page and then jump to the center after a few milliseconds. The jump is very noticeable on the live website.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wprggrm2/4/

*The jump doesn't show up in the JSFiddle, but it does on the live site; this is just to show you how I'm doing it in action!

So any ideas for alternative solutions that would avoid this jump? I mean I'm guessing this is a common situation.

Comment: You abuse floats. Looks like you don't really need them: http://jsfiddle.net/wprggrm2/6/

Comment: FWIW, the jump is caused by the delay in the browser loading all the page content, then the `window.onload` event fires once the page is loaded. You *could* minimise this with `document.ready`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` on `header-inner` and `text-align:center` on `header`.

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#header_inner {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wprggrm2/5/

Answer (score 0):

You just need `max-width` on the `header-inner` element [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wprggrm2/7/)